# Put result of forecast::ma() as a matrix and compute RMSE

Tags: r, time-series

I am really new to R. I am trying to calculate some MA[n] forecasts in R.
Here is my code,

```
# simple reproducible example
set.seed(0); factory <- round(rnorm(84), 1)
library(forecast)
factory.ts <- ts(factory, start = 1947, frequency = 12)
fit_EMA <- ma(factory.ts, order=5)
```

It works fine. Below is what `fit_EMA` looks like in R console. But I don't like the format as I couldn't find a way to take those fitted points for further usage. For example, how can I extract a row or column?

```
       Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
1947    NA    NA  0.80  0.24  0.12 -0.20 -0.46 -0.06  0.40  0.42  0.26  0.20
1948 -0.34 -0.58 -0.36 -0.32 -0.18 -0.36 -0.32 -0.30 -0.10 -0.02  0.20  0.34
1949  0.48  0.32 -0.10 -0.08 -0.22 -0.54 -0.48 -0.34 -0.20  0.08  0.38  0.38
1950  0.74  0.54  0.66  0.58  0.56  0.16 -0.02 -0.60 -1.04 -0.70 -0.38 -0.18
1951  0.10  0.34  0.58  0.26  0.28  0.28  0.48 -0.04 -0.32 -0.56 -0.54 -0.66
1952 -0.80 -0.38 -0.28 -0.32 -0.60 -0.34 -0.28 -0.10 -0.14  0.20  0.00 -0.06
1953  0.06  0.28  0.24  0.34  0.18 -0.24 -0.62 -0.38 -0.20 -0.06    NA    NA
```

Also, how can I calculate RMSE or other error methods? `forecast::ma` or `TTR::SMA`, `TTR::EMA` doesn't give a calculated error measures in summary. Or I have missed a library function?

Comment: 1. can you run `dput(factory)` and add the results to your question? 2. With package brings `ma`? 3. Did you show `factory.ts` or `fit_EMA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `forecast::ma()` is always a `"ts"` object. Although your `fit_EMA` appears as a matrix when you print it to screen (because `frequence = 12` so you have 12 columns), it is essentially a vector. You can use `str(fit_EMA)` to inspect it. You can do

```
mat <- matrix(fit_EMA, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
```

to get a matrix. Then `mat[1, ]` gives the fitted values for the first year (year 1947).

Getting RMSE is so straightforward that a function / library routine is not needed. Do:

```
MSE <- mean((fit_EMA - factory.ts) ^ 2, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 0.55876
RMSE <- sqrt(MSE)
# [1] 0.7475025
```